# Psychology of intelligence

Tags: educational-psychology

I studied some cognitive psychology of problem solving. But I havent studied the psychology of intelligence in depth.

I wanted to ask, to what extent do IQ/psychometric tests predict academic performance?
Einstein was said to have a high IQ and there are maths/physics prodigies out there.

What intelligence limitations limit an average person to achieve similar academic achievements such as of Albert Einstein's?

Any reference to research on psychology of intelligence is welcome.

Comment: Then what academic measure would you prefer?

Comment: How come those 70% of the people in the study that is in the question you posted, arent like Albert Einstein?  your answer isnt even fully relevant. I also asked what limits a person from becoming someone like Alert Einstein?

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate, since in its current form it is hard to tell the difference between the two questions, as reflected in the comments. You can still edit your question to disambiguate yours, and make it clear how your question differs. Ideally, even incorporating the other question and answer into your given question as a basis. To attract attention you can then ping me by writing a comment direct at me using '@Steven'.